# Hide field when empty in PHP

Tags: php, joomla

Unfortunately I don't know much about PHP. This code is from a component, I just want to change it. And now an individual price is displayed, if one is available, otherwise the standard price of 0.00. But now I want that nothing is displayed, unless the field for the individual price is not empty. So instead of 0.00 there should be nothing at all, unless I add something manually. Can someone help me?

```
if ($showPrice) {
$price = $row->price_text ?: EventbookingHelper::formatCurrency($row->individual_price, $config);
?>
<br/>
<div class="kurzinfo"><?php echo $price; ?></div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Hey @Colette Admotion I've added a condition !empty($row->individual_price) to the if statement. This condition checks if the individual_price field is not empty before displaying the price. If the field is empty, nothing will be displayed, as you requested.

if ($showPrice && !empty($row->individual_price)) {  // Your existing code  }

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This does not seem to work completely. I need to be a little clearer: If nothing is entered, a price of 0.00 is always displayed. And only if an individual price is entered, the price is overwritten with it. But the price of 0.00 should never be displayed, even if the individual price is empty.

Comment: Please try this one

<?php
if ($showPrice) {
 $price = $row->price_text ?: EventbookingHelper::formatCurrency($row->individual_price, $config);

 if($price != 0.00 || $price != '0.00') {
?>
 <br/>
 <div class="kurzinfo"><?php echo $price; ?></div>
<?php
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```php
<?php if ($showPrice) { $price = $row->price_text ?: EventbookingHelper::formatCurrency($row->individual_price, $config); if($price != 0.00 || $price != '0.00') { ?> <br/> <div class="kurzinfo"><?php echo $price; ?></div> <?php } }
```

// Seems good to me, but:

```php
if ($price <= 0){//code}
```

would also do it right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).